# problems calling shell from php with input parameters

Tags: php, shell

I am looking to call a shell script from php and pass input  parameters .i am not prolific with php ,but i tried using shell_exec function ,still not able to .

```
<?php
$a = "www.google.com";
echo shell_exec('sh test9.sh' , "$a");
?>
```

shell file is

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $a
```

Comment: The text inside your `shell_exec` will be `sh test9.shwww.google.com`.  Might want to make sure you include a space in there.

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

PHP's [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/shell_exec) does not accept variadic arguments; you'll need to pass *one string argument* with the entire shell statement.

```
echo shell_exec("sh test9.sh '$a'");
```

**Furthermore**, if `$a` containts untrusted content (like user input), **do absolutely never ever** forget to escape the value using the [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) function. Otherwise you'll be vulnerable to [shell injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Shell_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Thing you have to do

```
 echo shell_exec('sh test9.sh www.google.com');
```

and in sh script then

```
 echo $1
```

read about linux "sh" command , maybe you have to use the absolutpath of the sh "/a/b/c/d.sh" without the sh before the path

shell_exec has no second parameter